# Can bonuses of the same type stack indirectly?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Firstly, Pathfinder' rules as written are such that positive bonuses of the same type applied to an ability/skill/etc. **do not stack**, and that only the *highest* bonus applies (negative ones always stack). The implications of this are what I'm questioning, when they affect things that are tied together.

**Example scenario:**

The PC (let's call him Jimbo) is a Barbarian 1 / Cavalier 2 (Order of the Sword). 
Barbarians can rage, which grants Jimbo a +2 morale bonus to his strength and constitution ability modifiers.
The Order of the Sword lets Jimbo add a morale bonus to attack rolls against the target of his challenge (here, it will be a +1).

Now, say that Jimbo is raging and has declared his challenge against a certain enemy.
Because his attack modifier is affected by the morale bonus to his strength, is Jimbo unable to receive the +1 to his attack roll from his order's challenge ability?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Jimbo would receive both the bonus from rage and from his challenge because although they are both morale bonuses, his rage only affects his ability scores whereas the challenge provides a straight +1 to hit. The whole similar bonuses not stacking does not care about incidentals like the fact the morale bonus to strength gives him +1 to hit and damage.

If he were to receive [Bless](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/bless.html#bless), the +1 to hit would not stack but the +1 to saving throws against fear would still work.

If things did not stack as prescribed above, [Inspire Courage](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/classes/bard.html#inspire-courage) would be of little use to a barbarian as they level up.